# About the roots of cubic polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be the complex roots of the polynomial $P_3(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$.

Is there any known formula for calculating
$\alpha^2 \beta+\beta^2 \gamma+ \gamma^2\alpha \; , \;
\alpha \beta^2+\beta \gamma^2+\gamma\alpha^2$
(in terms of $a,b,c,d$)?

If no, can someone obtain it?

Answer (score 23):

Let $u=\alpha^2\beta+\beta^2\gamma+\gamma^2\alpha$ and $v=\alpha\beta^2+\beta\gamma^2+\gamma\alpha^2$. We have the following relations between the elementary symmetric polynomials $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$ of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ and the coefficients of $P_3$:
$$
e_1 = \alpha+\beta+\gamma = -\frac{b}{a} \\
e_2 = \alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha = +\frac{c}{a} \\
e_3 = \alpha\beta\gamma = -\frac{d}{a}
$$
We find
\begin{eqnarray*}
p & :=  u+v = & e_1e_2-3e_3 \\
q & :=  uv = & e_1^3e_3-6e_1e_2e_3+e_2^3+9e_3^2
\end{eqnarray*}
From this, you can obtain $u$ and $v$ solving $t^2-pt+q=0$.

Comment: Nice [resolvent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_%28Galois_theory%29)!

Comment: Nice answer[+1] but the problem remains that once you have solved the quadratic, it's a whole: you cannot say for example that $u$ is given by $u=(p+\sqrt{\Delta})/2$ and $v$ by $v=(p-\sqrt{\Delta})/2$... (I have tried in my answer to show where are the roots (pun intended) of this "twinship" of expressions $u$,$v$.)

Comment: I know. But at least we can calculate the values of the elements in the set $\{u,v\}$, which is a lot more than just saying that an explicit solution does not exist. And (as you have shown [+1]) we can say that for three of the permutations of the roots of $P$  (which are rotations of each other), we will have $u=(p+\sqrt{\Delta})/2$ and $v=(p−\sqrt{\Delta})/2$, while for the other three permutations of the roots, we will have $u=(p-\sqrt{\Delta})/2$ and $v=(p+\sqrt{\Delta})/2$.

Comment: Another interesting fact may be that $\Delta = V^2(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$, where $V(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = (\alpha-\beta)(\alpha-\gamma)(\beta-\gamma)$ (Vandermonde polynomial).

Comment: Interesting remark ... Not so surprizing afterwards when you think to the meaning of condition $\Delta=0$.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier, how are $u$ and $v$ related to the Lagrange resolvent? I'm trying to understand the philosophy under the Lagrange method, but I'm missing the general picture.

Comment: @zar I don't see a relation between the Lagrange resolvent and this problem. For the solution of this problem, you only need to see that $u+v$ and $uv$ are symmetric with respect to $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$. The rest is straight forward application of the [fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) and [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Answer (score 12):

Let

$$\cases{E(\alpha,\beta,\gamma):=\alpha^2 \beta+\beta^2 \gamma+ \gamma^2\alpha\\F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma):=
\alpha \beta^2+\beta \gamma^2+\gamma\alpha^2}$$

Your problem, strictly speaking, has no solution (but we will see hereafter that we can somewhat "bypass" this issue):

Here is a counterexample: Consider $P_3(x)=x(x^2-1)$ with roots $\{0,1,-1\}$.

Expression $E$ can take two different values depending on the order in which the roots are taken
:
$$E(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\begin{cases}-1 \ & \text{if} \ \ \alpha=1,\beta=-1,\gamma=0\\ \ \ \  1 \ & \text{if} \ \ \alpha=-1,\beta=1,\gamma=0\end{cases}.$$

As said in the other answers, the fundamental reason is that neither $E$ nor $F$  is symmetrical in $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, thus not invariant for certain permutations of the roots.

Of course, if you take $E+F$, you get a symmetrical polynomial in $\alpha, \beta, \gamma.$

But a slightly deeper analysis will be rewarding. In fact, **expressions $E$ and $F$ are conjugate** in a sense that will become clear, once we have seen the two following examples:

- taking $P_3(x)=x^3+x^2-x$, value $E(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\Phi\approx1.618$ is taken 3 times, and value $1-\Phi\approx-0.618$ is taken as well 3 times ($\Phi$ is the golden ratio).
- taking $P_3(x)=x^3+x^2+x$, (with some complex roots), value $-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is taken 3 times, and conjugate value (with the meaning of "conjugation in $\mathbb{C}$"): $-\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is taken 3 times.

Let us prove this "conjugation" by inspecting the set $S_3$ of $3!=6$ permutations of the roots $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$:

$$\binom{\alpha \ \beta \ \gamma}{\alpha \ \beta \ \gamma}: \ \ E(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=E(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$$

$$\binom{\alpha \ \beta \ \gamma}{\beta \ \gamma \ \alpha}: \ \ E(\beta,\gamma,\alpha)=E(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$$

$$\binom{\alpha \ \beta \ \gamma}{\gamma \ \alpha \ \beta}: \ \ E(\gamma,\alpha,\beta)=E(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$$

$$\binom{\alpha \ \beta \ \gamma}{\beta \ \alpha \ \gamma}: \ \ E(\beta,\alpha,\gamma)=F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$$

$$\binom{\alpha \ \beta \ \gamma}{\beta \ \gamma  \ \alpha}: \ \ E(\beta,\gamma ,\alpha)=F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$$

$$\binom{\alpha \ \beta \ \gamma}{\gamma\ \beta \ \alpha}: \ \ E(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$$

We have thus proved that, once a permutation is done on the roots, the value taken by $E$  is either unchanged (3 cases) or is the value of $F$ (the 3 other cases). As said by @CCorn in his answer, it is the mathematical object $\{E,F\}$ which is invariant under the action of $S_3$.

Remark: The first 3 cases correspond to a circular permutation: it is evident that $E$ has been built so that it is invariant by this type of permutation.

**Addendum:**

This is a little window on the origin of the so-called "Galois theory".

Have a look at the very pedagogical presentation [here](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m4010/polynom3.pdf) where it is explained how the ideas of Lagrange for solving the quartic equation where based on polynomials (called resolvents) that, under permutation, could take only a very small number of values. See also (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function). Another reference ([Galois theory: splitting field of cubic as a vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/49141)).

Comment: I have made clearer (I think so...) my presentation by an explicit work on the permutation, making easy the proof of the two values.

Answer (score 9):

No. $a,b,c,d$ are [symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) in $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and thus invariant under every permutation of $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$.
The expressions you want are invariant under some permutations, but not all, and therefore cannot be expressed in terms of only $a,b,c,d$.

Their sum is symmetric however, as @DougM's answer indicates.

**Update:** Their product too, and this results in a quadratic equation for the two expressions, as @ReinhardMeier's answer shows. Thus, the individual values of your desired expressions (call them $u$ and $v$) are not determined uniquely from $a,b,c,d$, but the set $\{u,v\}$ is.

Answer (score 6):

$\frac {b}{a} = -\alpha - \beta  - \gamma\\
\frac {c}{a} = \alpha \beta + \beta\gamma + \gamma\alpha\\
\frac {d}{a} = -\alpha \beta\gamma\\
-\frac {b}{a}\frac {c}{a} + 3\frac {d}{a} = (\alpha^2 \beta + \beta^2\gamma + \gamma^2\alpha)+(\alpha \beta^2 + \beta\gamma^2 + \gamma\alpha^2)$

I don't know if I can do much more that that.

Answer (score 6):

There can be no such formula. The coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are [symmetric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) of the roots $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$. Your polynomials $\alpha^2 \beta+\beta^2 \gamma+ \gamma^2\alpha$ and $\alpha \beta^2+\beta \gamma^2+\gamma\alpha^2$ are not symmetric functions, so they cannot be expressed as functions of the coefficients (since any such function would be symmetric).